# How can I add an npm module to my index.html file via webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, indexing

This seems like an obvious need to me, but not a common thing.

Basically, the first server request returns the index.html file.  However I have some JavaScript from an npm module I want to be included with the index.html file.

Preferably in the head like this.

```
<script>
   // npm JS code here
</script>
```

Is there a way to have webpack insert this code in my index.html file.

Obviously I can do this by hand however, this is tedious ...

Comment: Does https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/ not do what you want?

Comment: That appears to output the entire HTML file.  I just want to insert code into the HTML file I already have.